# Not able to sort the x axis on my line chart in Quicksight using a date field

Tags: sorting, linechart, amazon-quicksight

I have created a line chart to display the average survey score (1-5) for a question for multiple training sessions. The line represents the survey score and the x-axis represents the training id. The sort option using the training start date does not sort the X-axis correctly. My data is in the below format.

| training_id | Question text | Response [1-5] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| trn1 | Customer Satisfaction | 5 |
| trn1 | Customer Satisfaction | 4 |
| trn2 | Customer Satisfaction | 3 |
| trn2 | Customer Satisfaction | 4 |
| trn1 | Reaction Score | 1 |
| trn1 | Reaction Score | 7 |

I tried sort the training_ids on the x axis using the sort options providing the training start date as the sort parameter . The sort option prompts me to add either a count or a count distinct aggregation for the training start date. I chose the count distinct option but the x-axis does not sort correctly by the date. I request your help to assist me with sorting.